# Modify xml using python

Tags: python, xml, jenkins, amazon-s3

I have an xml file already generated by python and it looks like this. It has multiple items.

[xml_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snWaz.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<channel>
    <title>title-name-xyz</title>
    <link>http://dist.stage.xyzgauri.com/qa/partner/mac.xml</link>
    <description>Most recent changes</description>
    <language>en</language>

<item>
<title>Version 3.0.22.4</title>
<sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
    https://dist.stage.xyzgauri.com.com/qa/partner/mac_notes.html
</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
<pubDate>Thu, 12 Nov 2015 04:38:23 -0000</pubDate>
<enclosure
    url="https://dist.stage.xyzgauri.com/qa/sandisk/InstallCloud.3.0.22.4.pkg"
    sparkle:version="3.0.22.4"
    sparkle:shortVersionString="3.0.22"
    openlength="30455215"
    type="application/octet-stream"
    sparkle:dsaSignature="MCwCFHvf7peesvwR0AhRbZxTViLarxcjfd758mHPbnOW6wA=="
    sparkle:status="live"
/>
```

```
<item>
<title>Version 3.0.10.4</title>
<sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
    http://dist.stage.xyzgauri.com/qa/partner/mac_notes.html
</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
<pubDate>Tue, 03 Nov 2015 04:31:18 -0000</pubDate>
<enclosure
    url="http://dist.stage.xyzgauri.com/qa/partner/InstallCloud.3.0.10.4.pkg"
    sparkle:version="3.0.10.4"
    sparkle:shortVersionString="3.0.10"
    openlength="29709636"
    type="application/octet-stream"
    sparkle:dsaSignature="MCwCFDPvLPr7lYkrx5L5XCDbhXYqrFkGzLtLePK6ng=="
    sparkle:status="live"
/>
```

I need to use python to change the sparkle:status from "live" to "expired" for the older version 3.0.10.4. This xml is later pushed to S3.
I am a newbie to python and hence wondering how to implement this. I can even create a whole new jenkins jobs to get this xml and modify it and then push to S3.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Post the xml instead of a screen shot so we can cut and paste. We generally don't write solutions from whole cloth here. Poke around a python `lxml` 'XPath` tutorial and see what you come up with. Then you'll have a script to post.

Comment: i just modified the post. Would that help? Thank you!!

Comment: That helps but you still need to take a first swipe at a script. Here's a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+lxml+xpath+tutorial&gws_rd=ssl) that will help.

Comment: Thank you. I am working on it. And Sorry, i am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) solution using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) package where you can avoid any looping through all elements as may be required of an XPath solution. The script here runs an identity transform to copy all nodes and attributes as is and then runs a template specifically on all instances of the attribute `@sparkle:status` where its sibling in attribute set `@sparkle:version='3.0.10.4'`. Note too I had to declare the sparkle namespace in XSLT's header.

Below loads the XSLT script as a string but you can parse it from external file (saved in .xsl or .xslt format) like you do your XML file.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML LAND XSL
dom = ET.parse('Input.xml')

xslstr='''<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                         xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle">
          <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

            <!-- Identity Transform -->
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
              <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
              </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="enclosure[@sparkle:version='3.0.10.4']/@sparkle:status">    
              <xsl:attribute name="sparkle:status">expired</xsl:attribute>    
            </xsl:template>

          </xsl:transform>'''  

xslt = ET.fromstring(xslstr)

# TRANSFORM XML 
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)    

# SAVE OUTPUT
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True,  xml_declaration=True)
print(tree_out.decode("utf-8"))

xmlfile = open('Output.xml','wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try this out.